# Android Toolbar class not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-toolbar

I upgraded Android Studio to 1.2 today and I got this error.

> The following classes could not be found: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Create Class)

My build.gradle contains the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Would someone please resolve this issue for me?

Comment: Try Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: @CommonsWare still the problem persists.

Comment: Is the issue appearing from code or from xml styling?

Comment: Hmmm I cannot find the post that helped me out for references, but what fixed it for me was changing <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> under /res/values/styles.xml to <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> not sure if it works or not

Comment: I believe it is AS 1.2 [known issue](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)!

Comment: Instantiated and not found two very different things. I tried those workarounds also

Comment: Clean and rebuild I take it you tried?

Comment: @Aadi try deleting C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.AndroidStudioPreview1.2\system\caches or C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.AndroidStudio\system\caches depending on the version of Android Studio being used

Comment: Tried it still not working

Comment: what `Activity` your mainactivity extends?

Comment: show the activity which contains toolbar

Comment: MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity

Answer (score 2):

This problem can (occasionally) be resolved by invalidating caches

```
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart
```

See below:

[image: Invalidate Caches]

Answer (score 1):

> [Android Known Issue:](http://tools.android.com/knownissues) 
>   This is bug [170841](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170841) which will be fixed in version 1.2.3 of the
>   Android Gradle plugin.
>
> Workaround 1: First manually build the project, then manually sync the
>   project (using the Sync with Gradle files in the toolbar, or from the
>   Tools > Android menu), then finally press Refresh in the toolbar above
>   the layout editor. Workaround 2: Switch the Android Gradle plugin from
>   1.2.x to 1.1.3 for now. When 1.2.3 is released you can switch back to the 1.2.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` inside your project folder (`/lib`, `/libs` etc.)? Delete it! Then try remove it and make `Run - Clear project`.